# Shopify - Changing checkout totals

Tags: checkout, shopify

Anyone know if it's possible to change the total checkout value that is posted to Shopify while on the 'cart' screen?

I want to give certain customer types a wholesale discount (I'm using tags to differentiate the customer types). I'm using the shopify calculation to alter what the user will see but when sending to Shopify the totals are not discounted they are still the actual product price.

I can't seem to figure out where the totals are being stored so I can intercept them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter pricing on the fly. If you want to give someone a cheaper price, you will have to exchange the product(s) in the cart with the same products that have a cheaper price. In other words if you detect variant ID 12345678 in the cart with a price of $10.00 and you want to instead sell the variant ID 987654321 for $8.00 to the special customer, you'll have do that swap before allowing the completed checkout. Not the easiest thing in the Shopify world to do.

You could also just accept the $10 and send them a Thank You coupon worth $2.00 off their next purchase. Somewhat simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I kind of guessed this was the case but thought I'd ask anyway. I love Shopify but there's always a fly in the ointment on every project - guess I've just found another one!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's doable. Make a different variant for each customer type. On the last page, pick the right variant. It'd require some effort though.

The problem with this is though that someone may figure it out (esp. if you're doing it in javascript instead of, say, AJAX + App Proxy). Even then if someone figures out you have the same thing listed as a cheaper variant, the buyer can simply use the AJAX API to pick it instead. Now to stop that, 1) you must make changes using App Proxies and save the changes. 2) And then create a webhook for order completion and see if the changes match. If not, I don't know, send him an email saying don't be naughty and that the order's been canceled.

Basically, it's a lot of work, BUT it's doable. I did something like this for a similar problem.

P.S. If you aren't making a loss on the cheapest variant and can afford the remote chance that someone might figure the cheaper variant out, the task becomes much simpler. No need to use webhooks for verification and stuff. Just switch variants in the cart. Simple.

Comment: Hi Siam, thanks for the response. Yes, I figured the best way to offer different pricing was through variants. So now create 2 variants for each product. Then, using logic to distinguish customer type I hide/show the correct variant on the product page. Any customer who is clever enough to see there is a cheaper price deserves to get it cheaper!